# Can't access local XAMMP on laptop by phone

Tags: apache-http-server, android, xampp

I have a XAMPP running on Windows on port 8012. I can access it the laptop itself. When I enter my laptop's IP `192.168.1.101:8012` in my phone's browser, I am getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I am using a router, so the phone and the laptop are in the same network. My phone's IP is `192.168.1.104`. Also I have opened port 8012 in my Windows Firewall. When I turned off the firewall, it worked - the phone gets the page. But when I turn it on here is part of the firewall log:

```
2016-07-03 19:03:38 DROP TCP 192.168.1.104 192.168.1.101 49077 8012 60 S 1385359635 0 29200 - - - RECEIVE
2016-07-03 19:03:38 DROP TCP 192.168.1.104 192.168.1.101 49078 8012 60 S 1688611369 0 29200 - - - RECEIVE
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is your phone's IP address? How is it connected to your network?

Comment: Updated info in question.

Comment: I assume you can open the page from the computer itself by using `192.168.1.101:8012`. What happens if you disable the firewall on your computer?

Comment: @Zina please see the updated question

Comment: As it works when you disable the firewall that means that the firewall rule you have created is faulty. You should correct the firewall rule. Enable it in all profiles. Can you share a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the windows firewall -> inbound rules -> file and printer sharing ( echo request - icmpv4-in)

it should be set on enable

Comment: what does printer sharing have to do with apache?

Comment: it's the echo request. have you tried pinging the pc from your phone? it should be this case

Comment: I can ping my phone through my laptop. Firewall is dropping packets which I've allowed to accept. Why is that?

Comment: you have to check the reverse. can you ping your pc from your phone? if not, try my solution

Comment: I haven't tried the ping, but I changed the file and printer sharing to enabled. Still can't get the webpage.